# Quicksort implementation, can't find error

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I want to implement this quicksort algorithm with some different pivot strategy but there is some logical error in it. Can you please help me find it?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int arr[100],i,pivot,left,right,sum=0,a,n=10;

int partition();
void quickSort(int* ,int ,int );



void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int i,n=20;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
      arr[i]=rand()%100;
    }

    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
      cout<<"\t"<<arr[i];
    }

    quickSort(arr,n,i);

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
      cout<<"\n"<<arr[i];
    }

    getch();
}

int partition()
{
  // int i;
  // int sum=0;
  // int pivot;
  // stable_sort(arr,arr+3);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
       cout<<"\nsorted k elements\t"<<arr[i];
       // sum=sum+arr[i];
    }
    // cout<<sum;
    //cout<<"median is "<<sum/3;
    pivot=arr[(i)/2];
    cout<<"pivotis value at position "<<pivot ;
    return pivot;
}

void quickSort(int arr[],int left,int right) 
{
      partition();
      right=n,left=0;
      int i = right, j =left;

      int tmp;
      int p=pivot;
      cout<<" m array of p"<<p;
      while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < p)
          i++;
        while (arr[j] > p)
          j--;
        if (i <= j) {
          tmp = arr[i];
          arr[i] = arr[j];
          arr[j] = tmp;
          i++;
          j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
    {
       quickSort(arr, left, j);
    }
    if (i < right)
    {
       quickSort(arr, i, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know you have a logical error?  Can you provide the result for a small sample input data set?

Comment: The title 'NO IDEA WATS THE PROBLEM' wasn't helping you, so I, err-- polished it. Did you try debugging this? Locating the error?

Comment: I is not declared in partition

Comment: You've requested help finding "the error." The more I look at this code, the more I'm convinced the error is **all of it**. Don't try to fix this code. Scrap it and start over using code that you know works. Once you've confirmed for yourself that it works, *then* start experimenting. Make a change and see whether it still works. If it doesn't, undo that change and try something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pivot value will always be the value of `arr[(i)/2]`, which is `arr[2]`, no matter which portion of the array you happen to be sorting at the time. Pass the values of `left` and `right` to `partition` so it knows which values to consider for the current call to `quickSort`.

Also, the values of `left` and `right` that you pass for the *initial* call to `quickSort` are 20 and 21, respectively, which surely isn't what you intended. You have an array of length 100, and you have initialized the first 21 elements, so you probably want to pass 0 and 21 for those parameters.

But the first thing you should probably do, if you want to test quicksort with a *different* pivot strategy, is to get it working *first* with a *typical* pivot strategy, like the one demonstrated in your textbook. Start with a *working* implementation, and only *then* should you start experimenting with variations. You should be able to find a working implementation in your textbook or your class notes.

Comment: thanks. but can you just tell me whether i have passed the values(function parameters) correctly between the different functions. or when calling those functions??

Comment: The only place you're *passing* values to anything is when you call `quickSort`. I've already told you you're passing the wrong values on the first call. If you were calculating `i` and `j` correctly, then I think the recursive calls might be OK, but you're not. (`j` starts out equal to `left`, and all you ever do to it afterward is decrement it; when you do expect it will ever be *greater* then `left`?) You're not passing *any* values to `partition`, and that's one of the many problems in this code.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any place you compare values from the array.

I suppose you should check this place:

```
    if (i <= j) {
      tmp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = tmp;
      i++;
      j--;
    }
```

Probably it should be:

```
    if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
      tmp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = tmp;
      i++;
      j--;
    }
```